# filter a log file by request

Tags: awk, logs, filter

I try to filter my log file by request. I want to filter all the request(that you can find on the 7th column:/userx/index...) that have  `(m=xxx and a=xxx)` or  `(m=xxx and doajax=xxx)` and only have the request with those parameters

For example:

```
192.xx.x.x - - [11/Apr/2017:09:59:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=xxxx&doajax=xxxx&action=xxxxx&id=x
192.xx.x.x - - [11/Apr/2017:09:59:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?detailed=1&id=amgervais
192.xx.x.x - - [11/Apr/2017:09:59:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=xxx&a=xxxx&dialog=x&actionId=x&prospectId=xx
```

result of the filter:

```
192.xx.x.x - - [11/Apr/2017:09:59:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=xxxx&doajax=xxxx&action=xxxxx
192.xx.x.x - - [11/Apr/2017:09:59:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=xxx&a=xxxx
```

I tried to use this command to look the request which have m=xxx and a=xxx but I don't know how to do for other case ( when I can find m=xxx and doajax=xxx) at the same time.

```
awk '$7 ~ /m=/' logfile | awk '$7 ~ /&a=/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's wrong with

```
awk '( $7 ~ /m=xxx/ ) && (( $7 ~ /a=xxx ) || ( $7 ~ /doajax=xxx/ )) {
    split($7,A,"&") ; $7 = A[1] "&" A[2] ;print ;} ' logfile
```

where

- `&&` stand for logical and,
- `||` logical or,
- `split($7,A,"&")` will split 7-th field into array, using & as separator,
- `$7 = A[1] "&" A[2]` change (not in file) 7-th field to selected sub-field
- `print` print.

(this can be one lined, I break line for readability).

this give

```
192.xx.x.x - - [11/Apr/2017:09:59:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=xxxx&doajax=xxxx
192.xx.x.x - - [11/Apr/2017:09:59:xx +0200] "POST /userx/index.php?m=xxx&a=xxxx
```

If you want full line with `doajax` :

```
 awk '/doajax/ { print ; next ; } 
 ( $7 ~ /m=xxx/ )  && ( $7 ~ /a=xxx/ ) { split($7,A,"&") ; $7 = A[1] "&" A[2] ;print ;}'
```

Comment: thanks it's work but Can I delete all the text that I find after the 3th '&'  in the case the request has m=xxxx&doajax=xxxx&action=xxxxx& and  the 2nd   when it has m=xxx&a=xxxx&?